# navigation submenu showing up before hovering parent

Tags: html, css, submenu

I have a horizontal nav bar and I set the submenu to show only when you hover over the parent but the submenus show up when I move my mouse even a couple inches below the parents.  I'm not sure how to fix that.

HTML:

```
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="nav">
          <ul class="mainmenu">
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#belize">Belize</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fernie">Fernie BC</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#montana">Montana</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#philippines">Philippines</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tahoe">Lake Tahoe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#kids">The Kids</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="woodworking.html">Woodworking</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="woodworking.html#furniture">Furniture</a></li>
                    <li><a href="woodworking.html#cutting">Cutting Boards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="woodworking.html#bandsaw">Bandsaw Boxes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="woodworking.html#keepsake">Keepsake Boxes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="woodworking.html#odds">Odds &amp Ends</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: rgb(51,51,51);
color: white;
}

.nav > ul {
list-style: none;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
}

.nav > li {
width: 230px;
border-bottom: none;
height: 50px;
line-height: 40px;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -4px;
}

.nav > ul > li {
list-style-type: none;
display:inline-block;
padding: 5px 35px 5px 35px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
line-height: 40px;
font-size: 25px;  
}

.nav > ul > li:hover {
 background-color: #009933;
}

ul.submenu {
position: absolute;
background-color: #141414;
list-style-type: none;
width: 190px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 60px;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: -35px;
opacity: 0;
}

ul.submenu li {
padding-left: 25px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.nav li:hover .submenu {
opacity: 1;
}

ul.submenu li:hover {
color: white;
}

.nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
display: block;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
background-color:  #009933;
color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your css change `margin-top: 15px` to `margin-top: 5px`

Set `display: none;` when it is hidding, so hover below the nav menu will not trigger it.

```
ul.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #141414;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 190px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

Add this to your `.submenu` so when it should show set to `display:block;`:

```
.nav li:hover .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

#### Now, the solution:

```css
/* *************************************     HOME PAGE      **************************************** */

#homeImage {
  background: url("fernielow.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 99%;
  margin-top: 450px;
}

h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

h1 a:hover {
  background-color: #009933;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  color: black;
}

h1 a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* *************************************     NAVIGATION      **************************************** */

body {
  background: url("");
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}


/* LOOK @ NAV AND THEN @ UL */

.nav>ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav>li {
  width: 230px;
  border-bottom: none;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}


/* LOOK @ NAV THEN @ UL THEN @ LI*/

.nav>ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 35px 5px 35px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.nav>ul>li:hover {
  background-color: #009933;
}

ul.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #141414;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 190px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul.submenu li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/* WHEN HOVER OVER NAV LIST, I WANT SUBMENU TO CHANGE */

.nav li:hover .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
}

ul.submenu li:hover {
  color: white;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #009933;
  color: black;
}


/* *************************************     CONTACT PAGE      **************************************** */

#contactInfo ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border: 5px black solid;
  margin-top: 175px;
  margin-left: 750px;
  width: 300px;
}

.contactAddress {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#contactInfo ul li a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 153, 51, 0.8);
  padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#contactInfo ul li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#contactInfo ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#contactInfo ul li a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* *************************************     ABOUT PAGE      **************************************** */

#aboutMe {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px black solid;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 800px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 550px;
  line-height: 35px;
}


/* *************************************     PHOTOGRAPHY PAGE      **************************************** */

.picContainer {
  width: 1032px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 23%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border: 5px black solid;
}

.picContainer h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.pic {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 5px black solid;
}

hr {
  height: 10px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -3px black inset;
}


/* *************************************     TOP TO PAGE      **************************************** */

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Fixed/sticky position */
  bottom: 50px;
  /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
  right: 50px;
  /* Place the button 30px from the right */
  z-index: 99;
  /* Make sure it does not overlap */
  border: none;
  /* Remove borders */
  outline: none;
  /* Remove outline */
  background-color: white;
  /* Set a background color */
  color: black;
  /* Text color */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
  padding: 10px;
  /* Some padding */
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* Rounded corners */
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #009933;
  /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="sawdust.css" />
  <title>Sawdust &amp Splinters</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="mainmenu">
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#belize">Belize</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fernie">Fernie BC</a></li>
            <li><a href="#montana">Montana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#philippines">Philippines</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tahoe">Lake Tahoe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#kids">The Kids</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="woodworking.html">Woodworking</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="woodworking.html#furniture">Furniture</a></li>
            <li><a href="woodworking.html#cutting">Cutting Boards</a></li>
            <li><a href="woodworking.html#bandsaw">Bandsaw Boxes</a></li>
            <li><a href="woodworking.html#keepsake">Keepsake Boxes</a></li>
            <li><a href="woodworking.html#odds">Odds &amp Ends</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Go back to top</button>

  <div class=picContainer>

    <span id="belize">
   <h2>BELIZE</h2>
    <a href="photos/belize/pano.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/belize/pano-thumb.jpg" alt="San Pedro Panoramic"/></a>
    <a href="photos/belize/broken.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/belize/broken-thumb.jpg" alt="San Pedro Broken Bridge"/></a>
    <a href="photos/belize/beach.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/belize/beach-thumb.jpg" alt="San Pedro Beach"/></a>
    <a href="photos/belize/ruins.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/belize/ruins-thumb.jpg" alt="Xunantunich Ruins"/></a>
    <a href="photos/belize/zoo1.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/belize/zoo1-thumb.jpg" alt="San Pedro Zoo"/></a>
    <a href="photos/belize/zoo2.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/belize/zoo2-thumb.jpg" alt="San Pedro Zoo"/></a>
    <a href="photos/belize/zoo3.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/belize/zoo3-thumb.jpg" alt="San Pedro Zoo"/></a>
    <a href="photos/belize/zoo4.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/belize/zoo4-thumb.jpg" alt="San Pedro Zoo"/></a>
    <a href="photos/belize/cotton-tree.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/belize/cotton-tree-thumb.jpg" alt="Belize Cotton Tree"/></a> 
   </span>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <hr>
    <span id="fernie">
   <h2>FERNIE, BC</h2>
    <a href="photos/fernie/fernie.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/fernie/fernie-thumb.jpg" alt="Fernie"/></a>
   </span>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <hr>
    <span id="montana">
   <h2>MONTANA</h2>
    <a href="photos/montana/dog-park-mtns.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/dog-park-mtns-thumb.jpg" alt="Spanish Peaks"/></a>
    <a href="photos/montana/fairy-lake-bw.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/fairy-lake-bw-thumb.jpg" alt="Fairy Lake"/></a>
    <a href="photos/montana/gallatin.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/gallatin-thumb.jpg" alt="Gallatin River"/></a>
    <a href="photos/montana/grotto.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/grotto-thumb.jpg" alt="Grott Falls"/></a>
    <a href="photos/montana/hyalite.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/hyalite-thumb.jpg" alt="Hyalite River"/></a>
    <a href="photos/montana/mtns.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/mtns-thumb.jpg" alt="Mountains"/></a>
    <a href="photos/montana/natural.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/natural-thumb.jpg" alt="Natural Bridge Falls"/></a>
    <a href="photos/montana/palisades1.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/palisades1-thumb.jpg" alt="Palisades Mountain"/></a>
    <a href="photos/montana/palisades2.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/palisades2-thumb.jpg" alt="Palisades Falls"/></a>
    <a href="photos/montana/sunset1.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/sunset1-thumb.jpg" alt="Sunset"/></a>
    <a href="photos/montana/sunset2.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/sunset2-thumb.jpg" alt="Sunset"/></a>
    <a href="photos/montana/sunset3.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/montana/sunset3-thumb.jpg" alt="Sunset"/></a>
   </span>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <hr>
    <span id="philippines">
   <h2>PHILIPPINES</h2> 
    <a href="photos/philippines/temple.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/philippines/temple-thumb.jpg" alt="Sunken Temple"/></a>
    <a href="photos/philippines/katibawasan.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/philippines/katibawasan-thumb.jpg" alt="Katibawasan Falls"/></a>
    <a href="photos/philippines/camiguin1.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/philippines/camiguin1-thumb.jpg" alt="Camiguin"/></a>
    <a href="photos/philippines/camiguin2.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/philippines/camiguin2-thumb.jpg" alt="Camiguin"/></a>
    <a href="photos/philippines/camiguin3.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/philippines/camiguin3-thumb.jpg" alt="Camiguin"/></a>
    <a href="photos/philippines/camiguin4.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/philippines/camiguin4-thumb.jpg" alt="Camiguin"/></a>
    <a href="photos/philippines/camiguin5.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/philippines/camiguin5-thumb.jpg" alt="Camiguin"/></a>
   </span>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <hr>
    <span id="tahoe">
   <h2>LAKE TAHOE</h2> 
    <a href="photos/tahoe/tahoe1.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/tahoe/tahoe1-thumb.jpg" alt="Lake Tahoe"/></a>
    <a href="photos/tahoe/tahoe2.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/tahoe/tahoe2-thumb.jpg" alt="Lake Tahoe"/></a>
    <a href="photos/tahoe/tahoe3.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/tahoe/tahoe3-thumb.jpg" alt="Lake Tahoe"/></a>
    <a href="photos/tahoe/tahoe4.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/tahoe/tahoe4-thumb.jpg" alt="Lake Tahoe"/></a>
    <a href="photos/tahoe/tahoe5.jpg"><img class="pic" src="photos/tahoe/tahoe5-thumb.jpg" alt="Lake Tahoe"/></a>
   </span>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work.  Here's my jsbin if that helps. http://jsbin.com/habowijeju/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @QueenoftheNorth it is working, have you updated your margin-top? also the z-index

Comment: @QueenoftheNorth ok just replace the css you have with two I posted. `ul.submenu` and `.nav li:hover .submenu`

Comment: @QueenoftheNorth a jsbin for you http://jsbin.com/cuqezeguxa/1/edit?html,css,output, if you work on local, try hard reload to update the style sheet.

Comment: I tried your jsbin and it still had the same issue.  If I moved my mouse around the top of that first picture "San Pedro Panoramic" the submenu pops open even though I didn't hover over "Photography" or "Woodworking"

Comment: @QueenoftheNorth ok now check the updated code in my post, the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Will Advise adding the visibility property to be hidden on your "li" element. Opacity 0 still makes the "li" present and the "li" element extends with the submenu. See code below hope it helps.

```css
body {
background-color: rgb(51,51,51);
color: white;
}

.nav > ul {
list-style: none;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
}

.nav > li {
width: 230px;
border-bottom: none;
height: 50px;
line-height: 40px;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -4px;
}

.nav > ul > li {
list-style-type: none;
display:inline-block;
padding: 5px 35px 5px 35px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
line-height: 40px;
font-size: 25px;  
}

.nav > ul > li:hover {
 background-color: #009933;
}

ul.submenu {
position: absolute;
background-color: #141414;
list-style-type: none;
width: 190px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 60px;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: -35px;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}

ul.submenu li {
padding-left: 25px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.nav li:hover .submenu {
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}

ul.submenu li:hover {
color: white;
}

.nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
display: block;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
background-color:  #009933;
color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="nav">
          <ul class="mainmenu">
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#belize">Belize</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fernie">Fernie BC</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#montana">Montana</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#philippines">Philippines</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tahoe">Lake Tahoe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#kids">The Kids</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="woodworking.html">Woodworking</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="woodworking.html#furniture">Furniture</a></li>
                    <li><a href="woodworking.html#cutting">Cutting Boards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="woodworking.html#bandsaw">Bandsaw Boxes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="woodworking.html#keepsake">Keepsake Boxes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="woodworking.html#odds">Odds &amp Ends</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just add visibility:hidden; and visibility:visible;

```
 ul.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #141414;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 190px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: -35px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility:hidden; //add this
    }


    .nav li:hover .submenu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility:visible; //add this
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    breakpoint: 768,
    format: "multitoggle"
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #00ff00;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #00ff00;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen li:hover > ul > li {
  height: auto;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  color: #dddddd;
  background: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #00ff00;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 17px;
  color: #dddddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  top: 23px;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #00ff00;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  top: 23px;
  background: #00ff00;
  width: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
  background: #262626;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 19px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:after {
  top: 15px;
  right: 13px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
  background: #00ff00;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:before {
  top: 12px;
  right: 16px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.select-list {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- MenuMaker Plugin -->
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/menumaker/menumaker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-camera"></i> Photography</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Belize</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Fernie BC</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Montana</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Philippines</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Lake Tahoe</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">The Kids</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-magic"></i> Woodworking</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Furniture</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Cutting Boards</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Bandsaw Boxes</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Keepsake Boxes</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Odds & Ends</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-info"></i> About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```